# Changed application pool and site won't load

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8

In an effort to improve my Windows 2012 R2 server's use of physical memory, I changed a website from its own pool to the default pool. It would not load in that pool, so I changed it back to its own pool. I stopped and restarted the pool and the website, but it still won't load.

Do I need to restart IIS? The server?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try restarting just the relevant website in IIS.

Comment: I've done that, but it hasn't helped. I have a number of other websites on that server, so would prefer not to restart it.

Comment: When you say "it still won't load" do you mean the website won't load in the browser?

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean

Comment: Are there any clues in the IIS log files, or event viewer?